# Related to hyperledger composer playground place order issue

Tags: hyperledger

I want to build a medicine-network in hyperledger composer playground online.
I have created one cto file and one js file for that. I am new to this blockchain and want to create a business network for tracking a secure box. here participants are:- customer, Manufacturer, transport company
Asset- order,Securebox,beauty products in the securebox

I am unable to get the results for the placeorder event.

I posted the file which I have created

> securebox.cto

```
/**
 * securebox tracking
 */

namespace org.acme.securebox


/**
 * The types of BOX that could be moved
 */
enum BoxType {
  o SecureBox
  o NORMALBOX
  o OTHERS
}

/**
 * Status of an order
 */
enum OrderStatus {
  o ORDER_PLACED
  o IN_FIELD
  o IN_TRANSIT
  o DELIVERED
}

/**
 * The production type associated with a Box
 */
enum ProductionType {
  o SUGAR_MEDICINE
  o BLOODPRESSURE_MEDICINE
  o OTHER
}

/**
 * The Lock status associated with a Box
 */
enum BoxStatusType {
  o LOCK
  o UNLOCK
}

/**
 * A Person participant
 */
abstract participant User identified by email {
  o String email 
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}

participant Customer identified by custId extends User {
    o String custId
    o String address1 optional
    o String address2 optional
    o String county   optional
}

/**
 * A manufacturer of medicine
 */
participant Manufacturer identified by companyName  {
  o String companyName
}

/**
 * An order for a medicine/others to be fulfilled by a manufacturer
 * and dispatched to an orderer (Person).
 */
asset Order identified by orderId {
  o String orderId
  o ProductionType productiontype
  o OrderStatus orderStatus
  --> Customer customer
  --> Manufacturer manufacturer
}

/**
 * An Medicine asset, which is related to a order
 */
asset Medicine identified by medicineName {
    o String medicineName
    o BoxType box
    o OrderStatus movementStatus
    o ProductionType productionType
    --> Manufacturer owner
}

/**
 * An order for a medicine/others to be fulfilled by a manufacturer
 * and dispatched to an orderer (Person).
 */
asset SecureBox identified by secureBoxId {
  o String secureBoxId
  o BoxStatusType statustype
}

/**
 * Transaction to create an order
 */
transaction PlaceOrder {
  o String orderId
  --> Customer customer
  --> Manufacturer manufacturer
}

event PlaceOrderEvent {
  o String orderId
}
```

> securebox.js

```
'use strict';
/**
 *
 * @param {org.acme.securebox.PlaceOrder}  placeOrder - the placeOrder transaction
 * @transaction
 */
function PlaceOrder(placeOrder) {
    console.log('placeOrder');
    var factory = getFactory();
    var NS_M = 'org.acme.securebox';
    var NS   = 'org.acme'; 
    var order = factory.newResource(NS_M, 'Order', placeOrder.orderId);
    order.productiontype = 'SUGAR_MEDICINE';
    order.orderStatus = 'ORDER_PLACED';
    order.manufacturer = placeOrder.manufacturer;

    // save the order
    return getAssetRegistry(order.getFullyQualifiedType())
        .then(function (registry) {
            return registry.add(order);
        })
        .then(function(){
            var placeOrderEvent = factory.newEvent(NS_M, 'PlaceOrderEvent');
            placeOrderEvent.orderId = order.orderId;
            emit(placeOrderEvent);
        });

}
```

while submit the transaction, I am unable to get the output as expected.
Getting the error   # Instance org.acme.securebox.Order#1234 missing required field customer

Please help me out this

Comment: Error: Invalid or missing identifier for Type Order in namespace org.acme.securebox

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one sentence in **securebox.js** in `PlaceOrder()` function:

just add one line there:

```
order.customer = placeOrder.customer;
```